# Django DetailView - how to use 'request' in get_context_data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to modify context data, so I overrided `get_context_data`. I need the `request` variable to modify this context. So how can I get the `request` variable in `get_context-data`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have access to the request in `self.request` - the third paragraph [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) explains a little more.

*EDIT: The text referred to, in case it changes:*

> > The key part to making this work is that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on self; as well as the request (self.request) this includes the positional (self.args) and name-based (self.kwargs) arguments captured according to the URLconf.