# Django - Combining a datatable view and form view

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to put a table from datatables and a crispy form into one view so that I can display it on a single page in django. I am completely stuck on how to combine them as i'm still a newbie.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Views.py ------------- Datatable below
    class CustomerTable(XEditableDatatableView):
        template_name = "customers.html"
        model = Customer
        datatable_options = {
            'columns': [
                        ("Title", 'Title'),
                        ("Name", 'PoC', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("Email", 'PoCEmail', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("Location", 'Location', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ("DateAdded", 'DateAdded', helpers.make_xeditable),
                        ],
            'hidden_columns': ['ID'],
        }

           -----------Crispy Form below
        def CustomerView(request):
            form = CustomersForm(request.POST or None)
            success = False
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    form = CustomersForm()
                    success = True
            if request.POST.get('delete'):
                obj.delete()
            customer_form = CustomersForm()
            return render(request, 'customers.html', {'customer_form': customer_form})


urls.py ----------------
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.CustomerTable.as_view(), name='customertable'),
        url(r'^$', 'ISL.views.CustomerView', name='customersform'),
    )
```

Thanks for any help!
W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use get_context_data() method of your class like this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CustomerTable, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # do your magic here <<<
        # then
        context['customer_form'] = customer_form
        return context
```

First you are calling ancestor's get_context_data method via super built-in function, then you can append to context everything you want, in your example it is custom form. After this, you can access 'custom_form' in your template.

Unfortunately, i cant test it at the moment, but this method must be appended in ancestor by ContextMixin (django doc about this method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/).

Comment: Awesome its working! However, when I have the 'request' in the form, its saying "global name 'request' is not defined". Any idea how to get round that? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @BAW331, you can use link-word to your class instance: 'self'. In example:     self.request. Request also declared in your class ancestor. More, here from question: [request in get_context_data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243560/django-detailview-how-to-use-request-in-get-context-data). Good luck and have fun with coding!