# How to embed a form multiple times with ListView (and once with DetailView)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following listview and detailview structure. I would like to pass in a form to be shown with each object that is listed in the listview (and also with the one object when there is detailview). How can I get this to show up with each object?

```
class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Object
    ...
    date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 7)).date()
    queryset = Object.objects.filter(date=date)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class ObjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the form in your template file for that view! i.e. if your template file is `object_form.html` you will have to render the form in the for loop. For example:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<li>{{ obj.some_obj_field }}
<form>{# and in here render your form #}</form>
</li> 
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

... and likewise in `object_detail.html` but without the for loop since you'll have one object

Comment: how do i actually pass the form in? for example, with function based views I could just pass it in as context, but I can’t do that when it’s class based. so how do i make that form variable accessible?

Comment: you can override the get_context_data method to pass extra context

Comment: You can use [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

Comment: @mugoma can you access user information within get_context_data? I have a user object for each user and users must be signed in to access the given page. Can I access the user object within get_context_data?

Comment: @bernardo according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243560/django-detailview-how-to-use-request-in-get-context-data) the list view has a request attribute, which you can access `request.user` i.e. `self.request.user`. However, it think the [login required mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixinhttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) might be sufficient.

Comment: @mugoma that should definitely work, I was having trouble putting those together